# Poking into a Lie group with your finger

Tags: lie-groups, fourier-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, perturbation-theory, flows

I consider this as a differential geometry problem. I have asked some
of my classmates who are more interested in that, and also looked into
some literature, but none of what I've found seems to help.

#### Context

Thanks to the Peter-Weyl theorem, on any compact Lie group there's a
set of nice smooth functions that span the functions spaces of
interest, and form an orthonormal basis in suitable sense. The
simplest case is the circle group, where the nice functions are the
trigonometric functions.

On any compact Lie group, there's also a natural metric, so we can
define operators like the Laplacian or the Hodge star naturally which
depend on a choice of metric.

I notice one thing on the circle group: the nice functions are also
nice with respect to the Laplacian. They are the eigenvectors, whose
eigenvalues are known.

#### Question

1. I wonder if this is also the case for an compact Lie group (or more
   generally homogeneous spaces): does the set of good functions tell
   us a lot about the Laplacian or even more general operators? How
   much can we know from them in particular for the spectrum?
2. If 1. is true, what happen then when we perturb the natural metric
   on the compact Lie group a bit (for example, by some Ricci flow)?
   How will the eigenvalues and eigenvectors change correspondingly?
   Til what extent does this description (if any) breaks down, for
   example when two first distinct eigenspaces collapse to each other?

Any related pointers or suggestions will be highly appreciated. I'm
very curious about what happen: just think of you are poking your
finger into a 2-sphere (as a homogeneous space). How will the nice
functions change? Thank you very much.

Comment: Re:#1, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219109/explicit-eigenvalues-of-the-laplacian/219112#219112 ; won’t Ricci flow *preserve* the invariant metric?

Comment: I should have said that the perturbation does not respect the group structure necessarily.