# On how to diagonalize a Casimir element

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, string-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$I'm trying to read the physics paper [Two Dimensional QCD as a String Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9212149). I'm struggling with my ignorance about some computational aspects regarding Lie algebras.

Section 2.3 of the aforementioned paper states:

> The representations of $\U(N)$ are labeled by the
>   Young diagrams, with
>   $m$ ($m\leq N$) boxes of length $n_{1}\geq n_{2} \geq \dotsb n_{m} \geq 0$. Such a representation $R$ has dimensions $d_{R}$ and Casimirs $C_{2}^{\U(N)}(R)$ given by \begin{gather*}
> C_{2}^{\U(N)}(R)=N\sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}(n_{i}+1-2i); \\
> d_{R}=\frac{\Delta(h)}{\Delta(h^{0})}, \\
> \Delta(h)=\prod_{1\leq j \leq N}(h_{i}-h_{j}), h_{i}=N+n_{i}-1, h_{i}^{0}=N-i.
> \end{gather*}

**Clarification:** The statement *"$C_{2}^{\U(N)}(R)$ are Casimirs of the group"* does not make sense because of the fact that the quadratic Casimir element $C_{2}$ of $\U(N)$ is by definition a bilinear form on the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra of $\U(N)$ and the $C_{2}$ shown in the paper is a number. I suppose that what the author write as $C_{2}^{\U(N)}(R)$ is the eigenvalue of $C_{2}^{\U(N)}$ associated to the representation $R$ labeled by the partition $(n_{1},\dotsc,n_{m})$.

**The question:**

I'm asking for your kind help to identify some references where I can learn how to derive the formulas from above and possibly for other cases such as $\SU(N)$, $\SO(N)$ or some symplectic groups if possible.

I'd even be happy if someone could recommend a physical derivation of the formulas.

Comment: My own preferred description would be in terms of a "highest weight" of the irreducible. In fact, the same computation would apply to any Verma module, not only their irreducible quotients... Is this the sort of thing that would address your question?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment paul garrett. I'm familiar with the construction that obtain the highest weight representations of a Lie algebra from its Cartan subalgebra and its set of positive roots. If I understand well, your'e suggesting me that I should compute use the [theorem of highest weight representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_of_the_highest_weight) to compute the irreducible representations of some Lie algebra and then use something like the [Weyl dimension formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula) to obtain ...

Comment: ... the formulas I need. My problem is basically that I'm not so good in computing such things on concrete examples and I'm not convinced that I were capable to compute the formulas of my question.It would be very beneful for me to see a reference with explicit computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.3696 for derivation.

Let $E_i^j$ be the ${\rm U}(N)$ generators and $V$ be the fundamental representation. Decompose $V^{\otimes k}$ by the Schur-Weyl duality and apply the second Casimir $C_2 = E_i^j E_j^i$ to $V_R^{{\rm U}(N)} \otimes V_R^{S_k}$.

After some computation, $C_2$ becomes a sum over the permutations $\sum_{r \neq s} (rs)$. This is a sum of Jucys-Murphy elements whose eigenvalues are the contents of the box; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jucys%E2%80%93Murphy_element). By summing the contents over $R$, you can derive the Casimir eigenvalue $C_2^{{\rm U}(N)}(R)$.

That paper of Gross also gives $C_2^{{\rm SU}(N)}(R)$. His result agrees with Freudenthal's formula of $C_2=\langle \mu,\mu+2\rho\rangle$ by recalling that the Dynkin label $(m_1 , m_2 , \dots , m_{N-1})$ is related to the partition $(n_1, n_2 , \dots, n_N)$ by
\begin{equation}
m_i = n_{N-i} - n_{N+1-i} \ge 0.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're right that by "the Casimirs" the authors mean the eigenvalues of the quadratic Casimir operator on the irreps in question — this is a common phrasing in the physics literature.

For $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, the Young diagram with $m$ rows of lengths $n_i$ corresponds to the highest weight $\mu=\sum_i n_i\lambda_i$ (cf. e.g. [these lecture notes](https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2018/fs/401-2334-00L/sc/Beisert.pdf)). From there, the Weyl dimension formula cited in your comment should give the dimensions. For the Casimir eigenvalues, [these notes](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/webpage/Casimir3.pdf) may be of help. Note that there may be factors of 2 (and possibly of the dimension of the irrep) by which conventions used in the physics and mathematics literature may differ in defining the eigenvalues.

Comment: The specific formula for Casimir eigenvalues is the one of Casimir-van der Waerden-Freudenthal mentioned in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/219112).